# how to fix we don't have jp@gc - chrome driver config file in config element in Jmeter even we installed the selenium webdriver plugin

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Need solution to add browsers in jmeter , not able to add the config element for browsers even we add selenium webdriver plugin in plugin manager.Please help me.

need to add the browser in config element of jmeter

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **restart JMeter after any plugin installation**.

In order to ensure that everything went well you need to check the presence of:

1. `jmeter-plugins-webdriver-x.x.x.jar` file in the "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Presence of the following dependencies in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath):

   ```
   selenium-chrome-driver, opentelemetry-sdk-trace, jsyntaxpane, 
   opentelemetry-semconv, selenium-api, netty-common, opentelemetry-sdk,
   opentelemetry-exporter-logging, opentelemetry-sdk-common, 
   opentelemetry-exporter-common, selenium-remote-driver, netty-buffer,
   netty-resolver, async-http-client, async-http-client-netty-utils, 
   netty-transport, netty-codec-http, selenium-support, netty-reactive-streams,
   htmlunit, selenium-http, netty-handler, opentelemetry-sdk-metrics, 
   selenium-firefox-driver, selenium-ie-driver, failsafe, htmlunit-driver, 
   netty-codec, htmlunit-xpath, opentelemetry-api, opentelemetry-context,
   htmlunit-cssparser, opentelemetry-api-logs, opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-spi,
   commons-exec, htmlunit-core-js, neko-htmlunit, selenium-edge-driver,
   selenium-chromium-driver, byte-buddy, selenium-json, jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter,
   opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure, guava, selenium-java, opentelemetry-sdk-logs
   ```

If you still cannot see WebDriver Sampler and related Configuration Elements - check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries (it would be also a good idea to [enable JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging)), maybe you're suffering from a some form of a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell), i.e. you have previous WebDriver Sampler installation which is not compatible with the latest one or it conflicts with another installed plugin

Normally given you:

1. Perform clean installation of the [latest stable JMeter version](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)
2. Perform clean installation of the latest stable [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
3. Install **Selenium/WebDriver Support** plugin
4. Restart JMeter

You shouldn't see any issues.